# Empty view appears in unexpected place in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I have this layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/mapbox_fill_white"/>



    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
    </View>


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I add the below view, **it appears above the linear layout, but I want it to be below layout**. Why is it going above the layout? How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use attribute **android:layout_below** to show it below LinearLayout ,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="asdf"
            android:background="@color/mapbox_fill_white" />
    </LinearLayout >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View >
</RelativeLayout >
```

> **android:layout_below** -- Positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID. Accommodates top margin of this view and bottom
>   margin of anchor view.
>
> Must be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".

check [RelativeLayout LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are using is in a Relative layout,to show this View below your Linear layout you have to assign the rule layout_below for View,provide a id to your linear layout and then in your View put

```
  android:layout_below="@id/your_linear_layout_id"
```